# Merge close enough points in contours

Tags: opencv, geometry, nearest-neighbor, flann

I'm getting some info from image with Canny algorithm and findContours function.

Sometimes I get too many noisy points in some images which contains hairs or any other detailed stuff. I wonder how can I merge close enough points with OpenCV. For example I wish I could merge all points which are distanced from each other on less then X. (sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) < X I mean).

I heard that OpenCV has it's own wrapper around FLANN, but I'm not sure how do I use it.

And yeah, I want merging to be done on all contours awared of each other, not inside each contour individually.

Answer (score 0):

Use DBScan Clustering. on bounding rectangles.